# Issue reading req.body content when sending application/x-www-form-urlencoded from postman -- bodyparser already used

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

Like the title says. I am sending multipart form data from postman with a few text fields as well as an image. However when I console.log(req.body) I get

```
{
  '------WebKitFormBoundaryCpNHg1P01X54QAVr\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name': '"customerID"\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '1\r\n' +
    '------WebKitFormBoundaryCpNHg1P01X54QAVr\r\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="make"\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    'honda\r\n' +
    '------WebKitFormBoundaryCpNHg1P01X54QAVr\r\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="model"\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    'accord\r\n' +
    '------WebKitFormBoundaryCpNHg1P01X54QAVr\r\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="year"\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '2020\r\n' +
    '------WebKitFormBoundaryCpNHg1P01X54QAVr\r\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="color"\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    'white\r\n' +
    '------WebKitFormBoundaryCpNHg1P01X54QAVr--\r\n'
}
```

If I console.log(req.body.keyName) i always have undefined. I have already implemented what similar posts have suggested i.e using

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
 extended: true
}));
```

But it does not work still. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Code snippets follow.

server.js

```
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
 extended: true
}));

app.use(cors());

app.use('/users', userRouter);
app.use('/offers', offerRouter);


app.listen(PORT, (err)=>
{
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

route

```
const multer =  require('multer');

//required for mulitpart-formdata
const diskStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: "uploads/",
    filename: (req, file, call_back) => {
      //Prepend date to the filename or anything that makes
      //the file unique so it won't be overwritten

      call_back(null, Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname);
    },
  });
const upload = multer({ storage: diskStorage });

router.post("/request", upload.single("file"), (req, res, next) =>
{
    GetBucket();
    console.log(req.file);
})
```

postman[image]

Comment: to handle `multipart` data you need a different parser such as `multer` or `busyboy`. Multer is highly recommended as it is easy and simple to use
https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: Yeah I've used multer before didnt think i needed i though. Thanks I will try it now

Comment: Okay,  I've written the answer, please upvote and accept if you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

To parse a multipart request you need Multer or BusyBoy. I would suggest Multer (https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) as it is simple and easy to use, here is an example using Multer

```
const Multer = require('multer');
// create multer instance
const multer = Multer({
  storage: Multer.MemoryStorage, // we want to save parsed body in RAM
  onError: function(err, next) {
      console.log(err);
      next(err);
  }
});

function myController("/multipart/request", multer.single('name'), (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.body.name);
});
```

Note: Use multipart request if you are sending files along with your request, otherwise you can use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `application/json` which can be parsed by body parser

Comment: Yeah so I just implemented multer and I am sending from postman application/x-www-form-urlencoded which includes text fields and a file  and i still have the same result

Comment: Request you to update your code and add a screenshot of your postman request

Comment: In postman, choose `form-data` as the option while defining keys

Comment: what is your key name in postman request? It should be `file`

Comment: You can edit your answer, request you to update the code and add a postman request's screenshot

Comment: Okay I did its all there now

Comment: Add a print statement for the `file` in your `diskStorage.filename` function and see if it gets populated.

Comment: Just noticed, should be "/uploads". Make sure you have a directory created. Also if this doesn't work try memory storage first

Comment: I tried that. I have the folder. I used the same process with an angular app with 0 issues. I am thinking there is an issue with postman at this point. It makes no sense.

Comment: Maybe, try memory storage as well.

Comment: It ended up being an issue with Postman. Thanks for trying :P I ended up making a test frontend and was able to send the request fine

Comment: Great, please accept and upvote my answer if you find it helpful